# Can you use two different pseudo elements on one element on CSS?

Tags: html, css, userstyles

I make userstyles, in other words, third party CSS or custom CSS, and I'm replacing text with `content` property and the `before` and `after` pseudo elements. The problem is, to completely hide the original text, I have to set the original element's `font-size` to 0. This also hides things set in place with the `hover` pseudo element. I was going to just apply the `hover` properties to my `before` pseudo element, but then I would have to use 2 pseudo elements, which I don't think is possible. But, I'm not sure. Here's a sample similar to my code.

```
a.class[href="link"] {
 font-size: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
hover: 
}
 a.class[href="link"]:hover {
 background-color: black;
}
a.class[href="link"]:before {
 font-size: 16px;
 visibility: visible!important;
 content: "This text replaced what showed before";
}
```

a.class[

Comment: `:before:hover`, is fine as long as you have that other `:before`.

Comment: You may find it helpful to distinguish between _pseudo-elements_ which are preceded by a double-colon, like `::before` and `::after` and _pseudo-classes_ which are preceded by a single-colon like `:hover`, `:focus` and `:target`.